# c# EF 6.2 Change dbContext modelBuilder default schema sql Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm using entityframework 6.2.0, and I'm on a multi-tenant architecture, I have to change the schema every time I change the country.
in the 1st access to the application I point to the correct schema, on the other hand if I change the country entityframework does not change the default schema because it calls OnModelCreating only once.
[image]

I made a method to force the call to OnModelCreating but I couldn't find how to delete the old modelBuilder.configuration first.

do you have any idea on how i can change the schema each time i change the country please ?

I found similar questions, but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

Comment: Side note: `I have to change the schema every time I change the country` - Do you also start a new instance with every change of country or maintain a (new) instance per country? Personally I would not try to use a single instance and have it switch schemas when the country switches...

Comment: thanks igor . did you mean thant i have to instantiate a new ContainerBuilder in global.asax every time i change the country? like this :    
       
  ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
                builder.RegisterType<TenantService>().As<ITenantService>().InstancePerRequest();
                builder.RegisterType<BasePouvoirsDbContext>().As<IBasePouvoirsDbContext>().WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "connectionString",
                    (pi, c) => c.Resolve<ITenantService>().GetConnectionStringName()).InstancePerRequest();
IContainer container = builder.Build();